# Extract characters of single word following :

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds

I would like to extract the name of the drug, where "Drug:", "Other:",etc precedes name of drug.
Take the first word after every ":", including characters like "-".
If there are 2 instances of ":", then "and" should join the 2 words as one string.  The ourpur should be in a one column dataframe with column name Drug.

Here is my reproducible example:

```
my.df <- data.frame(col1 = as.character(c("Product: TLD-1433 infusion Therapy", "Biological: CG0070|Other: n-dodecyl-B-D-maltoside", "Drug: Atezolizumab",  
"Drug: N-803 and BCG|Drug: N-803", "Drug: Everolimus and Intravesical Gemcitabine", "Drug: Association atezolizumab + BDB001 + RT|Drug: Association atezolizumab + BDB001+ RT
")))
```

The output should look something like this:

```
output.df <- data.frame(Drugs = c("TLD-1433", "CG0070 and n-dodecyl-B-D-matose", "Atezolizumab", "N-803 and N-803", "Everolimus and Intravesical", "Association and Association"))
```

This is what I've tried, which didn't work.
Attempt 1:

```
str_extract(my.df$col1, '(?<=:\\s)(\\w+)')
```

Attempt 2:

```
str_extract(my.df$col1, '(?<=:\\s)(\\w+)(-)(\\w+)')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not so familiar with R, but a pattern that would give you the matches from the example data could be:

```
(?<=:\s)\w+(?:-\w+)*(?: and \w+(?:-\w+)*)*
```

Then you could concatenate the matches with `and` in between.

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=:\s)` Positive lookbehind, assert `:` and a whitespace char to the left
- `\w+(?:-\w+)*` Match 1+ word chars, followed by optionally repeating `-` and 1+ word chars
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `and \w+(?:-\w+)*` Match `and` followed by 1+ word chars followed by optionally repeating `-` and 1+ word chars
- `)*` Close non capture group and optionally repeat

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/J82kat/1/)

To get all the matches, you can use str_match_all

```
str_extract_all(my.df$col1, '(?<=:\\s)\\w+(?:-\\w+)*(?: and \\w+(?:-\\w+)*)*')
```

For example

```
library(stringr)
my.df <- data.frame(col1 = as.character(c("Product: TLD-1433 infusion Therapy", "Biological: CG0070|Other: n-dodecyl-B-D-maltoside", "Drug: Atezolizumab",  
"Drug: N-803 and BCG|Drug: N-803", "Drug: Everolimus and Intravesical Gemcitabine", "Drug: Association atezolizumab + BDB001 + RT|Drug: Association atezolizumab + BDB001+ RT
")))
lapply(
str_extract_all(my.df$col1, '(?<=:\\s)\\w+(?:-\\w+)*(?: and \\w+(?:-\\w+)*)*')
, paste, collapse=" and ")
```

Output

```
[[1]]
[1] "TLD-1433"

[[2]]
[1] "CG0070 and n-dodecyl-B-D-maltoside"

[[3]]
[1] "Atezolizumab"

[[4]]
[1] "N-803 and BCG and N-803"

[[5]]
[1] "Everolimus and Intravesical"

[[6]]
[1] "Association and Association"
```

Comment: That worked.  For my context, I changed to sapply to achieve a vector output instead of a list output with lapply.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```r
:\s*\b([\w-]+\b(?:\s+and\s+\b[\w-]+)*)\b
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/6ZGQBn/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```r
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\w-]+                   any character of: word characters (a-z,
                             A-Z, 0-9, _), '-' (1 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                             and something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
                               (1 or more times (matching the most
                               amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      and                      'and'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
                               (1 or more times (matching the most
                               amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w)
                               and something that is not a word char
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [\w-]+                   any character of: word characters (a-
                               z, A-Z, 0-9, _), '-' (1 or more times
                               (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
```

[**R code**](https://tio.run/##jVJda8IwFH3vr7iUPSTTSMXBRpmMVYcMxjaGb1bkmkYNpE1JUkfF/@6STlDYy55y77kf59xDzOlUtoNiA48MCnQ42BgsBeFaDWEMaAd8hwa5E4ZwEn8aXTTcpTB/m7Lh3WgEsto0VuoK5jthsG7jPsSZ1EpvJUeVwmSWJPfJ8cP5cgoVK3QheKtYxqasROW0lYUIQ1PTbFN4duKglTw0Ja49CtEZf2cPyQiwKiCbzI5X2GX0ZS@MHy0b2/W9Vs7gXtggA2ai5NLhWlbXXNZqLtEF9XjFCz3IplmSDH3wNT/@szn0RjGlNFJybdC0xDojq62hUYmO74QNFnts1aUrVIp0zt8Er72oNM/tbZ6vySLPv9myF8KnAPb8OeHxwLlEb6lPYhoFbb97sa5VS85Mfdg0FQ9ayYFCjdYJclj02XDZB8@msLZiHHc2ecWRblzduL@foNtO4VI/nX4A):

```r
my.df <- data.frame(col1 = as.character(c("Product: TLD-1433 infusion Therapy", "Biological: CG0070|Other: n-dodecyl-B-D-maltoside", "Drug: Atezolizumab",  
"Drug: N-803 and BCG|Drug: N-803", "Drug: Everolimus and Intravesical Gemcitabine", "Drug: Association atezolizumab + BDB001 + RT|Drug: Association atezolizumab + BDB001+ RT
")))
library(stringr)
matches <- str_match_all(my.df$col1, ":\\s*\\b([\\w-]+\\b(?:\\s+and\\s+\\b[\\w-]+)*)\\b")
Drugs <- sapply(matches, function(z) paste(z[,-1], collapse=" and "))
output.df <- data.frame(Drugs) 
output.df
```

**Results**:

```r
                               Drugs
1                           TLD-1433
2 CG0070 and n-dodecyl-B-D-maltoside
3                       Atezolizumab
4            N-803 and BCG and N-803
5        Everolimus and Intravesical
6        Association and Association
```